# Reference request for derivatives of complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, complex-numbers

I have been searching for reference for derivatives of complex numbers. All I found so far were texts that were too convoluted for me to grasp. I was (and still am) searching for a **reference that is aimed at beginners to complex analysis**.

I have one more question in relation to this:
1. Is derivative of a complex function the same as taking derivatives of real functions ?
Just to make it unambiguous:
$$\frac{d}{dx} x^2 + 3x + 9$$ is 
$$2x + 3 + 0$$

so, for complex functions will it be the same.. ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all the standard formulas for derivatives of elementary functions (not including the absolute value function) work over the complex numbers.

You might try http://people.math.gatech.edu/~cain/winter99/complex.html

Comment: So, derivative of $z^3 + 4z^5$ will be found the same way as if it was a real function?? Which comes out to be $3z^2 + 20z^4$

Comment: This is correct.  "Elementary functions" includes polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

For a gentle introduction to complex numbers and complex variables, especially if you're studying on your own:

Begin with [this excerpt from Stewart's **Calculus**](http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/ESSENTIAL%20CALCULUS/upfiles/topics/ess_at_12_cn_stu.pdf) and Chapter 5 (pp. 89-114) in Keith R. Matthews' online text [**Elementary Linear Algebra**](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~dli/matthews.pdf). Then go through John B. Reade's [**Calculus with Complex Numbers**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/041530847X).